# Cannot instantiate implementation type AuditRepository[T] for service type IAuditRepository[T]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm getting an error message when trying to add dependency injection:

**Cannot instantiate implementation type AuditRepository[T] for service type IAuditRepository[T]**

I've researched all the possible reason that can cause this error, including an abstract class for the implementation, but this does not apply to me.

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IAuditRepository<>), typeof(AuditRepository<>));
```

**IAuditRepository.cs**

```
public interface IAuditRepository<T> where T : class
{
   Task<Audit> GetByEntity(T entity);
}
```

**AuditRepository.cs**

```
public class AuditRepository<T> : IAuditRepository<T> where T : class
{
   private readonly AppDbContext context;

   public AuditRepository(AppDbContext context)
   {
      this.context = context;
   }
   
   public async Task<Audit> GetByEntity(T entity)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

***Note***: I have many entities so it would not be practical to do something like:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IAuditRepository<CustomerAccount>), typeof(AuditRepository<CustomerAccount>));
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IAuditRepository<Quote>), typeof(AuditRepository<Quote>));
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IAuditRepository<Address>), typeof(AuditRepository<Address>));
....
....
```

Comment: The default Dependency Injection framework can't handle unbounded generics. It expects concrete types. Try adding the NuGet package 'Scrutor'

Comment: Huh? DI *can* handle open generics. Can you provide more details of the exception being thrown?

Comment: Your code works here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OjocNm. Seems like we miss something important so we need more details from you. In general, the possible reasons might be:

1) the built-in IoC found multiple AuditRepository<> implementation and cannot understand which one should be instantiated;

2) you miss some injections to your AuditRepository<> implementation and therefore IoC is unable to resolve service for injected type AND instantiate your Repository.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue...the the DI code was effectively being done twice. The code below must've been the first time it got registered. And then my code registered explicitly a 2nd time. Additionally the code below was not registering it as a generic.

```
private static IEnumerable<Assembly> Assemblies
    {
        get
        {
            var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) ?? string.Empty;
            List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>
            {
                Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(path, "Business.dll")),
                Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(path, "DataAccess.dll")),
                Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(path, "WebServices.dll")),
                Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(path, "DataAccess.dll")),
            };
            return assemblies;
        }
    }

public static IServiceCollection RegisterCustomServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Assemblies
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract)).ToList()
            .ForEach(classType => classType
                .GetInterfaces()
                .Where(interfaceType => interfaceType.Namespace.EndsWith(".Interfaces", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)).ToList()
                .ForEach(interfaceType => RegisterInterface(services, interfaceType, classType)));
```